# Why is my docker file assuming Python 2.7?

Tags: python, docker, pip, python-2.7, ros

I am working on a pc with ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
My python version is 3.8.5

I am trying to build a docker image with the following Dockerfile

```
FROM ros:kinetic-robot
LABEL maintainer="olala7846@gmail.com"

# Install Dataspeed DBW  from binary
# adding Dataspeed server to apt
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] http://packages.dataspeedinc.com/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-dataspeed-public.list'
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys FF6D3CDA
RUN apt-get update

# setup rosdep
RUN sh -c 'echo "yaml http://packages.dataspeedinc.com/ros/ros-public-'$ROS_DISTRO'.yaml '$ROS_DISTRO'" > /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/30-dataspeed-public-'$ROS_DISTRO'.list'
RUN rosdep update
RUN apt-get install -y ros-$ROS_DISTRO-dbw-mkz
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
# end installing Dataspeed DBW

# install python packages
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# install required ros dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y ros-$ROS_DISTRO-cv-bridge
RUN apt-get install -y ros-$ROS_DISTRO-pcl-ros
RUN apt-get install -y ros-$ROS_DISTRO-image-proc

# socket io
RUN apt-get install -y netbase

RUN mkdir /capstone
VOLUME ["/capstone"]
VOLUME ["/root/.ros/log/"]
WORKDIR /capstone/ros
```

However it fails when installing the requirements:

```
attrdict==2.0.0
gevent==1.4.0
gevent-websocket==0.10.1
h5py==2.6.0
python-engineio==3.11.2
python-socketio==4.4.0
numpy==1.13.1
Pillow==2.2.1
scipy==0.19.1
keras==2.0.8
tensorflow==1.3.0
ujson==1.35
wsaccel==0.6.2
```

specifically when trying to install numpy.

Before installing the requirements it shows me this message

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
```

Why? In which part did I specified Python 2.7??

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you're going to love this: You need to use `python3-pip` and `pip3` in your Dockerfile.

When you use `apt install python-pip` you are installing the Python 2.7 version of pip. Hopefully this is something that will be resolved in the near future now that the 2.x run of Python has reached EOL.

Hope this gives you what you need